# AngularJS: Child directive that is appended by its parent cannot find its parent's controller

Tags: angularjs, parent-child, using-directives

I'm building a directive that will create a list of inputs.  When you begin entering information into the first input an empty input is appended below the one you are working in.

I have this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OD9vOtSjWhsaBtpiAQu1?p=preview) working for the first input.  The trouble is that the second input doesn't append anything.

I get this error: Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'parent', required by directive 'child', can't be found!

I suspect I need to go about adding the new inputs differently but I am unsure how.

I've checked out other post on Stack Overflow and they've been helpful in getting this far but none of them address the issue of maintaining communication with the parent controller.

Here is the parent directive:

```
app.directive('parent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<child name="0"></child>',
    controller: function($scope, $compile, $element) {

      // adds a new input within the parent 
      this.addChild = function(counter) {
        $element.append($compile('<child name="' + counter + '"></child>')($scope));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the child directive:

```
app.directive("child", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    require: '^parent',
    controller: function($scope, $attrs) {

      $scope.x = $attrs;
      $scope.directiveModel = "";

      $scope.$watch('directiveModel', function() {
        $scope.$parent.myModel[$attrs.name] = $scope.directiveModel;
      });

    },
    template: '<div><input type="text" name="{{x.name}}"  ng-model="directiveModel"></div>',
    link: function($scope, $element, attr, parentCtrl) {
      var fieldCounter = 0;
      var oldLength = 0;
      $scope.$watch('directiveModel', function() {
        // logic to determine if a new input needs to be added based on directiveModel's length
        // only add inputs when directiveModel.length is going from 0 to 1
        if ($scope.directiveModel.length == 1) {
          if (oldLength === 0) {
            fieldCounter++;
            parentCtrl.addChild(fieldCounter);
          }
        } else if ($scope.directiveModel.length === 0) {
          if (oldLength == 1 && fieldCounter > 0) {
            fieldCounter--;
            $element.remove();
          }
        }

        oldLength = $scope.directiveModel.length;
      }, true);
    }

  };
});
```

and here is the markup

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <parent></parent>

    <pre>{{myModel | json}}</pre>
  </body>
```

Comment: Please add code to your question, not just plunkr

Comment: like ogc-nick said: please add your code

Answer (score 0):

Observations:
- If you keep typing on the first field and then delete everything, then write again. It successfully keeps creating new input fields
- I think the problem is with the scopes.  your first child directive (the one in the parent template) creates a scope that is actually the scope of the parent directive naturally, but all the other directives have their own scope.  check it on the dev tools, inspect element.
- I also tried things with emit and on.  same results.
- So only your first directive is healthily created and it keeps creating new children.  maybe try to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned the the whole idea of a parent and child directive.  Instead I used one directive that deals with all the data manipulation and performed an ng-repeat over the stored data.

Here's my app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile, $element) {
  $scope.myModel = [
                    {
                        value: ""
                    }
    ]; 
});

app.directive("stackingInput", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            item: "=",
            index: "="
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="item.value"></div>',
        controller: function($scope, $element, attr){
            var fieldCounter = 0;
            var oldLength = 0;
            $scope.$watch('item', function() {
                    if ($scope.item.value.length == 1) {
                        if (oldLength === 0) {
                            fieldCounter++;
                            $scope.$parent.myModel.push({value: ""});
                        }
                    } 
                    else if ($scope.item.value.length === 0) {
                        if (oldLength == 1 && fieldCounter > 0) {
                            fieldCounter--;
                            $scope.$parent.myModel.splice($scope.index, 1);
                        }
                    }

                    oldLength = $scope.item.value.length;                   
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can you can add this line to your markup within the ng-controller element

```
<stacking-input ng-repeat="item in myModel" item="item" index="$index"></stacking-input>
```